# How to show current time in JavaScript in the format HH:MM:SS?

Tags: javascript, datetime

How do I show the current time in the format HH:MM:SS?

Comment: Here is my code..http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/yd99X/

Comment: But the problem is that it is having PM and AP I don't need that .Secondly 24 format

Comment: @user2648752 check my answer demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fKKSb/

Comment: Um ... Why is the question tagged [tag:date], even though the user is asking for the time?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fKKSb/) using javaScript only

**Update**

<kbd>[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fKKSb/311/)</kbd>

```
(function () {
    function checkTime(i) {
        return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date(),
            h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
            m = checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
            s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    startTime();
})();
```

Answer (score 172):

You can use native function `Date.toLocaleTimeString()`:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

This will display e.g.:

```
"11:33:01"
```

[MDN: Date toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
alert("The time is: \n"+n);
```

Comment: i think, this should be the accepted answer, cause it answers exactly the question, uses native function and is the shortest working code to get what is asked for.

Comment: 3:59:45 PM is what it gave me. That is not the requested format.

Comment: toLocaleTimeString is not a function

Comment: in one line `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()`

Comment: This totally depends on the system / browser settings. Sometimes you get "22:11:33 "sometimes "10:11:33 PM"

Comment: For those not liking the AM/PM for this, if you're getting it, can use: `new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(" ")[0];`

Comment: Actually use `(new Date()).toLocaleTimeString('eo', { hour12: false })`

Answer (score 82):

You can do this in `Javascript`.

```
var time = new Date();
console.log(time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds());
```

At present it returns `15:5:18`.  Note that if any of the values are less than 10, they will display using only one digit, not two.

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n7RFD/)

**Updates:**
For prefixed 0's try

```
var time = new Date();
console.log(
    ("0" + time.getHours()).slice(-2)   + ":" + 
    ("0" + time.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + 
    ("0" + time.getSeconds()).slice(-2));
```

Comment: yes But I need to add three column as written in question .Please read sir question .I need add time on first column and real time data on second column

Comment: You need to account for minutes and seconds < 10, as Tushar has done in his answer, or else it won't show a leading "0".

Comment: @CleverGirl I was trying to give simple answer so I wrote that.  Since you mentioned about prefixed 0's I would like to do this with [@user113716 's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3605248/1671639) which has be portrayed very clearly.

Comment: Also for prefixed 0's try `String(date.getMinutes()).padStart(2, "0");` this will add a 0 if not 2 digits.

Answer (score 46):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to do this.

```
var now = new moment();
console.log(now.format("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Outputs:

```
16:30:03
```

Comment: Thank you remus.  I will never again fall down the inglorious rabbit hole of js datetime manipulations.

Comment: Thanks man! Every one else makes everything so complicated!
This is the most succinct response for someone who needs to grab a quick line of code for a simple thing!

Comment: Hide the 120-odd bytes it takes to do this by including a 20k+ script! genius

Comment: Hey, I'm not saying you should always use it, but if you are already, why not do it the easy way 

Answer (score 37):

```
new Date().toTimeString().slice(0,8)
```

Note that toLocaleTimeString() might return something like `9:00:00 AM`.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen someone make a code example instantiating date without new Date()... is that normal to use (new Date) ?

Answer (score 21):

Use this way:

```
var d = new Date();
localtime = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
```

Result: 18:56:31

Answer (score 5):

```js
function realtime() {
  
  let time = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
  
  setInterval(() => {
    time = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
  }, 1000)
}

realtime();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="time"></div>
```

A very simple way using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) and [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```
setInterval(() => {
  moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
}, 1000)
```

**Sample output**

Using `setInterval()` set to 1000ms or 1 second, the output will refresh every 1 second.

> 3:25:50 pm

This is how I use this method on one of my side projects.

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.time = this.shared.time;
}, 1000)
```

Maybe you're wondering if using `setInterval()` would cause some performance issues.

[Is setInterval CPU intensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650134/is-setinterval-cpu-intensive)

> *I don't think setInterval is inherently going to cause you significant performance problems. I suspect the reputation may come from an earlier era, when CPUs were less powerful. ... - lonesomeday*
>
> *No, setInterval is not CPU intensive in and of itself. If you have a lot of intervals running on very short cycles (or a very complex operation running on a moderately long interval), then that can easily become CPU intensive, depending upon exactly what your intervals are doing and how frequently they are doing it. ... - aroth*
>
> *But in general, using setInterval really like a lot on your site may slow down things. 20 simultaneously running intervals with more or less heavy work will affect the show. And then again.. you really can mess up any part I guess that is not a problem of setInterval. ... - jAndy*

Answer (score 5):

Compact clock function:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    let d = new Date()
    console.log(`${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}:${d.getSeconds()}`)
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString('it-IT')
```

The `it-IT` locale happens to pad the hour if needed and omits PM or AM `01:33:01`

Comment: What does this code only answer offer over the existing solutions that show how to use `.toLocaleTimeString()`?

Comment: the 'it-IT' part means it outputs exactly as asked console.log(event.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT'));
// expected output: 01:15:30
if you don't include 'it-IT' then you are getting something like `1:15:30 PM` which misses the initial 0 and adds ` PM` which you'd have to strip away otherwise. I edited my answer to clear that up.

Answer (score 2):

This code will output current time in HH:MM:SS format in console, it takes into account GMT timezones.

```
var currentTime = Date.now()
var GMT = -(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()/60;
var totalSeconds = Math.floor(currentTime/1000);
seconds = ('0' + totalSeconds % 60).slice(-2);
var totalMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds/60);
minutes = ('0' + totalMinutes % 60).slice(-2);
var totalHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes/60);
hours = ('0' + (totalHours+GMT) % 24).slice(-2);
var timeDisplay = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
console.log(timeDisplay);
//Output is: 11:16:55
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to set time in a div(only_time) using javascript.

```
function date_time() {
    var date = new Date();
    var am_pm = "AM";
    var hour = date.getHours();
    if(hour>=12){
        am_pm = "PM";
    }
    if (hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }
    if(hour>12){
        hour = hour - 12;
    }
    if(hour<10){
        hour = "0"+hour;
    }

    var minute = date.getMinutes();
    if (minute<10){
        minute = "0"+minute;
    }
    var sec = date.getSeconds();
    if(sec<10){
        sec = "0"+sec;
    }

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =  hour+":"+minute+":"+sec+" "+am_pm;
}
setInterval(date_time,500);
<per>
<div class="date" id="time"></div>
</per>
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function realtime() {
  
  let time = moment().format('hh:mm:ss.SS a').replace("m", "");
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
  
  setInterval(() => {
    time = moment().format('hh:mm:ss.SS A');
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
  }, 0)
}

realtime();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Use

> Date.toLocaleTimeString()

```
// Depending on timezone, your results will vary
const event = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+00:00');

console.log(event.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
// expected output: 1:15:30 AM

console.log(event.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT'));
// expected output: 01:15:30

console.log(event.toLocaleTimeString('ar-EG'));
// expected output: ١٢:١٥:٣٠
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#try_it)