# Download With Current User Time As Filename

Tags: javascript, php, html, download

## In short

How can I make a file's name contain the user's local time upon **downloading** it?
Example:

```
<a href="/pizza.pdf" download="pizza-CURRENT-USER-TIME-HERE.pdf">Click here</a>
```

## In long

- I know I can give it the **server's local time** with PHP, as mentioned here:
  [How to get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-php)
- I know I can **print** the user's local time to the screen, with JavaScript, as mentioned here:
  [How to show current time in JavaScript in the format HH:MM:SS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229022/how-to-show-current-time-in-javascript-in-the-format-hhmmss)

What about the download having the **user's time in the name**?

With PHP, I know I can `echo` a variable into the file's name, like this:

PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$current_date = date('Y-F-j-h-i-s');
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/pizza.pdf" download="pizza-<?php echo $current_date; ?>.pdf">Click here</a>
```

Or, with JavaScript, I can print the user's local time in the **link** (or anywhere on the screen).

**How can I get the user's local time as the value for the download attribute?**

I'm open to using PHP, JS, JQuery, etc.

Comment: What role does PHP play here? Is `pizza.pdf` a static asset or server-side generated?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález let's assume PHP is not needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this most simply with the `onclick` attribute.

```
<a href="/pizza.pdf" download="pizza-CURRENT-USER-TIME-HERE.pdf" onclick="this.download='pizza-' + getFormattedTime() + '.pdf'">Click here</a>
```

Or, if you want to use Jquery:

In HTML (adding an id so we can select):

```
<a href="/pizza.pdf" download="pizza-CURRENT-USER-TIME-HERE.pdf" id="download">Click here</a>
```

In JS:

```
$("#download").click(function() {
    this.download= 'pizza-' + getFormattedTime() + '.pdf'
}
```

Now, when the user clicks the link, the download name will be changed immediately to the current time.

Here's an example for how to get the time (heavily based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229022/how-to-show-current-time-in-javascript-in-the-format-hhmmss)):

```
function getFormattedTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    // JavaScript months are 0-based.
    var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = today.getDate();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var mi = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    return y + "-" + m + "-" + d + "-" + h + "-" + mi + "-" + s;
}
```

Comment: Well, it would actually probably be a function call, like `getFormattedTime()`. I just wanted to signify that it is a string. Just amended my answer to show this.

Comment: OK, done. It's essentially the same code from the second link you posted above.

Comment: Ok, there you go.

Comment: Small note: variable m is used for both month and minute