# How add time local of my computer in may page html

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I like to display my time local in my page html , javascript , and i can use momentjs ? Please who can help me ?

Comment: You should try to search for what you are asking at least once before asking it in SO. Have you tried doing `new Date()`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229022/how-to-show-current-time-in-javascript-in-the-format-hhmmss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
document.body.textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
```

Comment: Thank you , it work excellent .