# How to write generic javascript function to get time format specified below

Tags: javascript, datetime

8:53 PM PDT - basically 12hrs format with AM/PM.
Irrespective of machine time format.

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Just get the hours, check if it's greater than 12. If it is, subtract 12 and change to PM.

Comment: You could also use the moment.js library, it has a time formatting function.

Comment: The question is: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/1169519)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using moment Timezone: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

then it's as simple as

`moment().tz('PDT').format('hh:mm A z')`

Comment: can we achieve without moment()

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229022/how-to-show-current-time-in-javascript-in-the-format-hhmmss just remove the ss part in that function, and add a hardcoded value of PDT in the return...