# Clear browser cache on background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, browser

In our company we have web app (backend spring, frontend angularjs) which displays lot of photos and they are used for some evaluations. Default browser is FF. After some time period (10-20min) the working with app is so slowen down that it is almost unusable. In that case user press Ctrl+F5 and it is OK again.
The question: exists any javascript method to clear cache or simulate Ctrl+F5 on background WITHOUT showing the confirmation dialog "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave..."?
Thanks a lot for help.

Regards

Comment: Could you disable cache entirely for the site rather then trying to empty? As specific things can be forced to refresh like images and .js files, but you can't do anything to empty a users entire cache for your website.

Comment: It looks like the symptoms of memory leaks / a big uncontrolled number of angularjs $watchers. Try profiling your app first before doing any other steps (just to be sure you know the root cause of the issue).

Comment: May be I found the issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650134/is-setinterval-cpu-intensive). On the page there is JS callback which every time sets interval 10ms for some canvas drawing (lines). I modified it to ged rid the setInterval and will see...